# Scroll to anchor on interior and exterior links

Tags: jquery

So I've found myself in quite the predicament. I'm using the attached code to do a simple scroll to an anchor in jQuery. The scroll to works when I'm on the page and it's scrolling to the anchor locally, but my problem arrises when I need to get back to the scroll to anchor on another page.

```
var scrollWin = function (selector) {
    var bar = jQuery(selector).offset().top;
    bar = bar - 80;
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: bar
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery('[href^=#]').click(function(e) {
    scrollWin (jQuery(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

I had found a code that works from exterior pages when the link changes from "#div" to "/#div" on interior pages, but changing the nav links on interior pages is not an option. Any and all help much appreciated, cheers.

**UPDATE**

So this is what I ended up going with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = jQuery(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
             jQuery('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

});

and then for external pages traveling back to the page with the anchor links

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
function goToByScroll(id){
   jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#"+id).offset().top - 80},'slow');
} 
if(window.location.hash != '') {
    goToByScroll(window.location.hash.substr(1));
}
```

});

now if you're offsetting space for say a sticky nav like myself, the window is going to load at the anchor point and then animate to the desired offset upwards. This isn't ideally what I was looking for, but this is the closest I could get.

Comment: Onload check if there’s a hash in the current URL, and if so scroll to it?